# Frigga's Protection multiple use in single battle

Tags: blood-rage

The card says

> You may pay 1 rage to prevent a figure of yours from being destroyed.

Can I pay 3 rage to prevent 3 figures from being destroyed in a single battle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, in the game of Blood Rage, you can use the Frigga's Protection card to save multiple units in one battle as long as you have sufficient rage. See this post from Thiago Aranha, one of the three authors of the rules of the game:

https://boardgamegeek.com/article/20522706#20522706